# When the effect of invigorating gemstone procs, does it do so before or after taking damage?

Tags: diablo-iii

The [invigorating gemstone](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/invigorating-gemstone)'s rank 25 effect is to heal the player when a control-impairing effect hits. Does this heal go before or after taking damage from said effect?

Example:

- An elite pack has the `frozen` attribute.
- I stand in the area where `frozen` is going to hit while having this gem equipped and at rank 25
- The `frozen` goes off
- Do I get damage here and heal 20% of my life after?
- Or do I heal 20% of my life here and get damage from the frozen blast after?

I'm asking because I play hardcore, so things like this can really matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, frozen doesn't count. At least it didn't when the gem first came out. I haven't used it since.

Second, it occurs AFTER the damage is taken.

You can check more in-depth details [here](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Invigorating_Gemstone).